# REGEX match two patterns between specific characters

Tags: php, regex

I know the title may be a little vague but I wasnt sure how to formulate it. I have a string that contains text that looks something like this:

```
$data["key1"] = "value1";

$data["key2"] = "value2";

$data["key3"] = "value3";

$data["key4"] = "value4";
```

I would like to match everything after `$data["` and `]"` and everything in between `= "` and `";` in the same match, so for example the results would be

```
Match 1 = {key1, value1}

Match 2 = {key2, value2}

Match 3 = {key3, value3}

Match 4 = {key4, value4}
```

So far I have been able to match the values with

```
/(?<=]\s=\s\")(.*?)(?=\s*\"\;)/
```

but I would also need the first part in the result as well and I'm not sure how to do so.

Also, is there a way to have it match if there is (or isn't) white spaces between characters?

for example

```
$data["key1"]= "value1";

$data["key2"]="value2";

$data["key3"] ="value3";

$data["key4"] ="value4" ;
```

Would also all match the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `preg_match_all`:

```
$input = '$data["key1"] = "value1";';
preg_match_all('/\$\w+\["(.*?)"\]\s*=\s*"(.*?)";/', $input, $matches);
echo "Match = {" . $matches[1][0] . ", " . $matches[2][0] . "}";
```

This prints:

```
Match = {key1, value1}
```

Comment: That works, but is there a way to also make it match cases where single quotes are used or double quotes? I tried adding |' after the double quotes but I didnt get the expected results.

Comment: @Alex It certainly can be made to work should your input have single quotes.  Just escape them with backslash.  [See the demo here](https://rextester.com/ANN3692).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following for each line. Basically you just need to search for each pair of quotes in each line should do the work.

```
// $output_array is an array which the first index is your key and second is the value
// for example, array( "key1", "value1")
$input_lines = '$data["key1"] = "value1"';
preg_match_all('/\"\w+\"/', $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Comment: But...this would also capture the `data` substring in the variable name `$data`.